# get multi line text centered with image in a div

Tags: html, css

Here is what my html element looks like (incorrectly).  I need the text to be vertically aligned in the middle:

[image]

The text doesn't have a line break, it just wraps around based on the size of the div.  The enclosing div is 200px, the image is 75 px, the image has a right margin of 15 px, and the text gets 110px to display.

```
.favorite {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    font-size:14px;
    height:75px;
}
.favImg {
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
    width:75px;
}

.favText {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150%;

    width:110px;
    float:right;
}

            <div class="favorite">
                <div class="favImg"><img src="http://localhost/images/icons/favorites-tennis.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" alt="Tennis"/></div>
                <div class="favText">Playing a sport alot and more</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tooooooo much of useless css. it can be done much simpler:

```
.favorite {
width: 200px;
font-size:14px;
height:75px;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.favImg, .favText{
display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.favImg {
margin-right:15px;
width:75px;
height: 75px;
background: #ff0000;
}

.favText {
line-height: 150%;
width:110px;
white-space:normal;
}
```

the line display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline; is just a way of enabling cross-browser inline-block:

"zoom: 1; *display: inline;" - is for the old IEs (like IE 7)
display: -moz-inline-stack - is for the old mozilla firefox.
if you'd rather not to use it (although there's no reason to avoid it), you can use just display:inline for the child nodes instead.

all the solutions with floats and tables seem unreasonably complex and questionable in this case. try to write simple code.

You don't need  to wrap every element in a div either:

```
<div class="favorite">
<img src="http://localhost/images/icons/favorites-tennis.jpg" class="favImg" alt="Tennis"/><p class="favText">Playing a sport alot and more</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use `display: table` for your parent container and `display: table-cell` for your child container.

Something like this:

```
.favText {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150%;
    height: 100%;
    width:110px;
    float:right;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fukW/1/)**):

```
.favorite {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    font-size:14px;
    height:75px;
}
.favImg {
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
.favText {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150%;
    height: 100%;
    width:110px;
    float:right;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 <div class="favorite">
     <div class="favImg"><img src="http://localhost/images/icons/favorites-tennis.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" alt="Tennis"/></div>
      <div class="favText">
           <div class="inner">Playing a sport alot and more</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Basically, add an `.inner` div to wrap the text inside of `.favText`, make `.favText` `display: table` and `height: 100%`, then give the `.inner` div `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.

When vertically centering things where there are unknown heights involved, this is a very quick and simple way to do it and will work even if you don't know the height of the container element OR the content element.

If your text was always going to be one line though, you could set `line-height: 75px` on your `.favText` div in your original code and just leave it at that (but if text wraps this is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `margin-top: 13.75px;` to `favText`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CC5pp/).